# Prove the following theorem without Hensel's lemma

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic, algebraic-number-theory

Let $P(X)\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$. Suppose that $P(X)\equiv 0$ has a root in $\mathbb Z/p^r\mathbb Z$ for every $r\geqslant 1$ and a fixed prime $p$. Prove that there exists a sequence of integers $(x_r)$ such that $P(x_r)\equiv 0\pmod{p^r}$ and $x_r\equiv x_{r-1}\pmod{p^{r-1}}$.

Can one prove this without any notion of Taylor's expansion or Hensel's lemma?

I tried to consider $P(x_{r-1}+tp^{r-1})$ for $0\leqslant t<p$. However I cannot connect the roots of $P(X)$ modulo $p^r$ to the roots of $P(X)$ modulo $p^{r-1}$. I cannot see the correct place to apply the condition that $P(X)\equiv 0$ has a solution in $\mathbb{Z}/p^r\mathbb{Z}$ for all $r$. I am not sure if I should do this forward or backward. From Hensel's lemma, it seems that one can obtain this sequence of integers "backward" since the integers $x_i$ are unique modulo $p^i$. However, I cannot prove this fact from the given conditions.

Thanks in advance; any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is the same as proving that $\Bbb{Z}_p$ (the ring of $p$-adic integers) is compact.

For each $r$ take one integer $y_r$ such that $P(y_r)\equiv 0\bmod p^r$.

Let $A_r = \{ a\in \Bbb{Z/p^r Z}, y_n \equiv a \bmod p^r$ for infinitely many $n\}$.

Since $\Bbb{Z/p^rZ}$ is finite it is clear that $A_r$ is non-empty.

Moreover $A_r=A_{r+1}\bmod p^r$.

Let $x_0=0$ then by induction on $r$, given $x_r$ take some $x_{r+1}\in A_{r+1}$ such that $x_{r+1}\equiv x_r\bmod p^r$.